# Is there a way to create a presence/absence matrix of polygons per cell in a grid using qGIS?

Tags: qgis, distribution, species, grids-sum

I'm working in QGIS with species distribution polygons and I want to know how many cells in a grid does the polygon overlap. I've tried creating random points within the polygon and then used `vector<Analysis<points in polygon` but I end up with gaps.

Can anyone help with this. I'm still learning GIS and I need to do this with over 1000 species.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the **Join Attributes by Location** tool from the toolar (*Vector > Data Management Tools > Join Attributes by Location*) and select your polygon layer as the *Target layer* and your grid layer as the *Join layer*. Then choose to take a summary and select any of the options (doesn't matter which if you're only interested in the count which is default):

[image: Join attributes by location]

The attribute table of the results should contain a `COUNT` field which tells you how many times a polygon overlaps a grid cell.

[image: Results]